# how to change Jslider value and pass to paintComponent?

Tags: java, swing

i am developing an application in which Brightness of image change as per user change the value of JSlider.
Jslider display on window but image is not loaded and i also don't know how to pass value of JSlider to paintComponent() method.

my code :

```
public class Neo_2010_Slider1 extends JFrame
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Container container ;
    private JSlider slider1 ;

    private JLabel lbl1 ;

    private JPanel panel1 ;

    private JTextField txt1 ;
    public Neo_2010_Slider1() {
        super("Slider");
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBackground(new Color(14555));
        setSize(new Dimension(400,400));
        setResizable(true);

        container = getContentPane();
        BorderLayout containerLayout = new BorderLayout();
        container.setLayout(containerLayout);

        lbl1 = new JLabel("Slider 1");


        /****************** TextField Properties ********************************/
        txt1 = new JTextField(4);



        slider1 = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL,0,1000,0);//direction , min , max , current
        slider1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma",Font.BOLD,12));
        slider1.setMajorTickSpacing(100);
        slider1.setMinorTickSpacing(25);
        slider1.setPaintLabels(true);
        slider1.setPaintTicks(true);
        slider1.setPaintTrack(true);
        slider1.setAutoscrolls(true);
        slider1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));

        slider1.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                txt1.setText(String.valueOf(slider1.getValue()));
                repaint();

            }
        });
        txt1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {    
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try
                {
                    slider1.setValue(Integer.parseInt(txt1.getText()));
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    txt1.setText("ERROR");
                    txt1.setToolTipText("Set Value in Range between 0 - 1000 ") ;
                }
            }
        });
        this.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e){
            }

            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                txt1.setText(String.valueOf(slider1.getValue()));                   
            }
        });

        panel1 = new JPanel();
        container.add(panel1, BorderLayout.WEST);
        panel1.add(lbl1);
        panel1.add(txt1);
        panel1.add(slider1);

        setVisible(true);
    }       

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
      Graphics2D g2d=(Graphics2D)g;
      try{
          BufferedImage src=ImageIO.read(new File("src.jpg"));

          BufferedImage dest=changeBrightness(src,0.5f);

          g2d.drawImage(dest,0,0,this);

          ImageIO.write(dest,"jpeg",new File("dest.jpg"));
      }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
      }
   } 

   public BufferedImage changeBrightness(BufferedImage src,float val){
       RescaleOp brighterOp = new RescaleOp(val, 0, null);
       return brighterOp.filter(src,null); //filtering
   }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new Neo_2010_Slider1();
    }
}
```

i also don't know that where to pass paintComponent method..
if anyone knows then please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what it is you how to gain, but `JFrame` doesn't have a `paintComponent` method, so it will never be called.

What I would do, instead is

- Load the source image as soon as you can and store it in variable (`masterImage` for example)
- Use a `JLabel` to show the image
- Use a `javax.swing.Timer` with a short delay (so 125 milliseconds) set so it won't repeat.  Each time the `JSlider`'s `stateChanged` event is raised, I would `restart` this timer.

When the timer finally triggers, I would update the "master" image's brightness and apply teh result to "image" `JLabel`'s as it's icon.

The reason for the timer is the fact that the operation of applying the brightness can not only take time, but can increase the amount of memory the application consumes.  You will want to reduce this to the absolute minimum if you can

Comment: Sir if you have simple example for that then will you just guide me for that.  i have create object of JFrame and called jf.paintComponet(getGraphics()) but it also not working.

Comment: if possible then just tell me how to display image ? where am i wrong  ? after that i will try by myself. where to use painrComponent() method or where to call it ? i will be so thankful to you sir please.

Comment: Take a look at [How to use labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html)

Comment: Yes, i have done it, i just have to add code add(Slider1) in constructor that i have added, and one i have to add is repaint method in statechanged listener of JSlider. thank you everyone.

Answer (score 1):

to get the value of a JSlider, you should add a changelistener.

```
slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener(){

    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
         // handle change

         JSlider source = (JSlider)e.getSource();
         methodeToHandleChange( (int) source.getValue() );

    }
});
```

see also [how to use a sliders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/slider.html)

**paintComponent**

the paintComponent method is a protected method, so it can not be called from the outside. However it is part of the painting mechanisme that can be invoked by calling the `repaint` method.

```
slider.repaint();
```

Comment: Sorry Sir, but i am not getting exact what you want to say, if it will possible then please will you give me some more description, if you are free.

Comment: `JFrame` doesn't have a `paintComponent` method.  No amount of `repaint`ing will ever update the image...not that the OP should be loading, updating or saving an image within a `paintXxx` method anyway...

Comment: Yes, i have done it, i just have to add code add(Slider1) in constructor that i have added, and one i have to add is repaint method in statechanged listener of JSlider. thank you everyone.